# ActionScript3 How completely delete value with key from dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary

Behavior of `Dictionary` confuses me:
I have a `Dictionary`, filled like bellow:

```
var playerControllers:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

playerControllers[id] = new PlayerController();
```

then, I'm deleting one of my controllers:

```
delete playerControllers[id];   //I also tried playerControllers[id] = null;
```

then:

```
for each (var playerController:PlayerController in playerControllers)
{
//"deleted" PlayerController exists! 
}
```

How to delete value with key from Dictionary?

Comment: Isn't there a method something like playerControllers.Delete(id) or remove(id) ?

Comment: `PlayerController` - is my own class. Before deleting it fron dictionary, I calling `onLeave` function. There is some code for erising player from scene. It's interesting, that there is another dictionary I'm deleting data from. But in this `for each` I'm using direck call for value in it (dictionary[id]), and it's returning my `null`, as axpected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help out.

`var playerControllers:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);`//Weak Reference

If you are using `Object as key`.we should use `weak reference` might help you in this case.

Even if you delete playerControllers[id] from stil in memory because dictionary class still hold that playerControllers[id] reference in dictionary.

For better understanding http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2